# Lightswitch get data from related datatable

Tags: c#, data-binding, visual-studio-lightswitch

In Lightswitch I have an order table that has a one to many relationship with a supplier table.

When the order has been completed in the Order screen, I would like to send an email with the order to the selected supplier.

Ideally, I'd like to do this in code (c#), but I can't seem to see a means of wiring up the email field from the supplier table in to code for the order class. All I can call is the suppler name picked up via the auto complete box.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and thought I should share it for anyone else who's stuck.

```
this.Orders.Supplier.Email
```

This didn't work for a list and details screen but did work for a details screen which makes sense.